# Unable to retrieve JSON data from web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have an external web service that has JSON data. I've validated that data is JSON through the JSON Validator website. However, the below code success function does not run at all. The web service requires that the email and password be passed through the url for the JSON data to be displayed.

The url to access the web service is as such:
http://example.com/Email/Password

How do I fix the below code to solve this issue. Any help whatsoever will be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#frmLogin").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var pm_url = 'http://example.com/';
            pm_url += $("#Email").val();
            pm_url += '/';
            pm_url += $("#Password").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: pm_url,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(){
                    alert("Success");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: You can add `error: function...`.

Comment: Is example.com is your server domain's? Or is that external?

Comment: A couple of things I'd check: Is the success alert happening?  If so, you may need a result argument in your callback function to access the resulting JSON.  If not, what is the response code?  Also, is the value of pm_url correct before you issue the ajax request?

Comment: Which jQuery version you are using? Add the `error` callback instead of just using `success` callback. Also, consider using .complete() after this call.

Comment: I added an error callback and got Cross-Origin Request Blocked. So, now trying to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issue, which has to do with security. The browser will not allow requests to be dispatched that are external to your domain unless you explicitly allow it to. [This](http://zinoui.com/blog/cross-domain-ajax-request) is a good article that details several ways to allow CORS requests, if you google around you will find much more.